# operator does not exist: text ->> unknown

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to take info from my json field, which is created using c#, [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KhNvZ.png)

```
SELECT "Price"->>'TotalPrice' FROM "Table"
```

but I have error in postgres

> ERROR:  operator does not exist: text ->> unknown LINE 1: SELECT
> "Price"->>'Price' FROM "ReadModel"... No operator
> matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add
> explicit type casts.

Comment: Check if the data type of `"Price"` (Why this case sensitive identifiers? They just make things more complicated than necessary...) really is `jsonb` or `json`... I guess it isn't...

Comment: The engine seems to think otherwise, it might be `text` (or some `varchar`, etc.). And I think the chances that the engine is wrong are very close to zero... Check again. Or, if you really think it's a bug in Postgres you've found, [edit] the question and provide a [example], i.e. the `CREATE` statements of the tables or other objects involved (paste the **text**, don't use images, don't link to external sites) and `INSERT` statements for sample data (dito) so that we can reproduce the issue. Also mention your exact Postgres version.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The error message is pretty obvious: your column is defined as `text` not as `jsonb` or `json`. But the `->>` operator only works with a `jsonb` or `json` column, so you will need to cast it:

```
SELECT "Price"::jsonb ->> 'TotalPrice' 
FROM "ReadModel"."MyListingDto"
```

---

Unrelated to your problem, but: you should really [avoid](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names) those dreaded quoted identifiers. They are much more trouble than they are worth it.